# How to print word based on column using Lua? Something like awk

Tags: awk, lua

I'm wondering if there is something similar to awk in Lua.
For example, I have the following string

```
"This is a cup of tea"
```

I want to print out

```
"cup"
```

by using the column number, is there such a function or I will have to create my own?

Finding words won't work as the word before and after might change.

Comment: `s:gsub('%S+','',n-1):match'%S+'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
s="This is a cup of tea"

function column(s,n)
    local p=string.rep("%s+.-",n-1).."(%S+)"
    return s:match(p)
end

for n=1,10 do
    print(n,column(s,n))
end
```

Answer (score 2):

Lua doesn't have the concept *column*. You need to do it manually:

```
local t = {}
for word in line:gmatch("%S+") do
  table.insert(t, word)
end
```

Then access `t` with the *column* number like `t[4]`.

Comment: If you only need the Nth column then don't bother with the table and just count and break.